# How to disable artisan serve

Tags: laravel, npm, serve

I tried to run `serve -s build` in my React app after running `npm run build`. 
I get the following error.

> Could not open input file: artisan

I think this artisan is from Laravel. How can I run npm `serve` command rather than Laravel's one.

Comment: temporarily rename artisan file in root path.

Comment: You need to be inside laravel folder ..